# Wrong SOAP Tags in PHP SOAP Request

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to send an SOAP request.

My request looks like this

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="someurl">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <RequestIndBApplication>
```

But my customer told me it has to look like this

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <process xmlns="someurl">
         <RequestIndBApplication>
```

I'm using an WSDL file i got from my customer. But i don't know how i can change the soap tag. is there a way to do this?

Here is my php code

```
$client = new SoapClient('urlofwsdlfile',array('trace' => true, 'exceptions' => true)); $params = new \SoapVar($xmlstr), \XSD_ANYXML);

$result = $client->__SoapCall('process', array($params));
```

$xmlstr contains the data as xml